# What is the proper way to manage a vector of unique_ptr's?

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

If I have a class which is managing a vector of `std::unique_ptr`s, what is the proper way to manage this resource? I have below a minimum working example. When running this code, however, a segmentation fault occurs. I imagine this is because `main`s reference to `bin` get's `std::move`d in `AContainer::addValue`, but I don't know for sure and I am not sure how to test that assumption.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class AnotherContainer;

class AContainer{
    public:
        void addValue(AnotherContainer& anInt);
        const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnotherContainer>>& getVals() const;
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnotherContainer>> ints;
};

void AContainer::addValue(AnotherContainer& anInt){
    ints.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<AnotherContainer>(&anInt)));
}

const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnotherContainer>>& AContainer::getVals() const{
    return ints;
}

class AnotherContainer{
    public:
        AnotherContainer(int val) : myVal(val){};
        int getVal() const{
            return myVal;
        }
    private:
        int myVal;
};

int main(){
    AContainer bin;
    AnotherContainer val1(1), val2(2);
    bin.addValue(val1);
    bin.addValue(val2);
    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnotherContainer>>& vals = bin.getVals();
    std::cout << "vals[0] = " << vals[0]->getVal() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that you're creating two instances of AContainer on the stack here :

```
AnotherContainer val1(1), val2(2);
```

and then wrapping the pointer to these references in the addValue calls:

```
bin.addValue(val1);
bin.addValue(val2);
```

so, when the call to the main function returns, the objects val1 and val2 created on the stack are deleted, but also deleted at the deletion of bin, because the smart pointers call the destructor on the objects they wrap, thus causing the segmentation-fault.

smart pointers are made to manage memory on the heap, allocated with the new operator, so for things to run smoothly you should initialize val1 and val2 this way :

```
AnotherContainer* val1 = new AnotherContainer(1);
AnotherContainer* val2 = new AnotherContainer(2);
```

(You will also have to make some changes in your methods for the program to compile)

Comment: This did work. I will have to read up on about 'stack' and 'heap', I've seen those terms thrown around a lot. Also, no need to change my methods, I can just call `bin.addValue(*val1)` and keep the method as-is. Thank you!

Comment: Note that it's a good habit to get into to use `std::make_unique<T>(args...)` instead of `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(args...))` - the former has better exception safety.